# Apache POI works with .xls but not with .xlsx

Tags: java, spring, primefaces, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I'm creating export with apache POI. When I'm using export to xls, with HSSFRow and HSSFCell, it is working perfect both locally and on server. But when I change it to xlsx, with XSSFCell and XSSFRow, it is working locally but not on server. It is giving me the following error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/core.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller@7621d6eb
```

Not sure why it is happening. Any ideas? The poi version is 3.11, I have tried with others as well with same result.

here is the PF export component:

```
 <p:commandLink styleClass="exportAllPages" ajax="false">
     <p:dataExporter type="xlsx" target="techData" fileName="tdam"
      pageOnly="false" postProcessor="#{global.postProcessXLS}"/>
 </p:commandLink>
```

Here is the exception I have in logs:

```
Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/core.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller@6e7530ef
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/core.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller@6e7530ef
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:503) ~[poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:3.11]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1425) ~[poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:3.11]
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:201) ~[poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:3.11]
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter.writeExcelToResponse(ExcelExporter.java:176) ~[primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter.export(ExcelExporter.java:73) ~[primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:97) ~[primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88) ~[jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813) ~[jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300) ~[jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108) ~[jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) ~[jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) ~[jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) ~[jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:270) [pjl-comp-filter-1.7.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:88) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) [catalina.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.59.B]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException: The part /docProps/core.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller@6e7530ef
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:486) ~[poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:3.11]
```

Comment: Look at your logfile, there you should see the reason.

Comment: I did, already. Nothing interesting. Same message. I will attache the whole expcetion to the question.

Comment: Try to change the path where you are saving the file, and where is the code for conversion. What format are you trying to export from and to?

Comment: I'm not saving it, I'm using primefaces exporter with postprocess. But it is not even comming to the postprocess. It is failing at the begining. I'm dinamically creating the file from the existing primefaces datatable. But even when I manually create the file with some data from the data base (even with face strings), if I use XSSFWorkbook, XSSFSheet, XSSFRow, it is working locally but not on server.

Comment: POI should provide some log-output why it failed to write the part, could be I/O related things like out of disk or something similar. Can you enable logging in POI via something like `-Dorg.apache.poi.util.POILogger=org.apache.poi.util.SystemOutLogger`

Comment: @DjordjeIvanovic Can you provide the code you're using to export to XLSX?